# How to "Add to Cart" button change text "Added" after ajax success

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I am new PHP developer, I have worked on shopping cart functionality "Add to cart" button click data save successful in database table. But the "Add to cart" button text not changed. How to resolve the issue?

**jQuery:**

```
var addedCart = 0;

  function advAddtocart(a_id){

    if (addedCart==1) {
      $("#paymentCart_"+a_id).html('Added');
    }

    var $this = $("#paymentCart_"+a_id);

    $($this).buttonLoader('start');
    setTimeout(function () {
        $($this).buttonLoader('stop');
    }, 3000);


    $("#paymentCart_"+a_id).attr("disabled", true);

    var id = $('.tour_reference'+a_id).attr('rel');
    var name = $('.tour_reference'+a_id).val();
    var service_type = $('.service'+a_id).val();
    var price = $('.rate'+a_id).attr('rel');
    var rfq_id = $('.quote_id'+a_id).val();
    var client_id = $('.user_id'+a_id).attr('rel');
    var service_id = $('.rfc_id'+a_id).attr('rel');

    // var service = service_type.toLowerCase().replace(/[^A-Z0-9]+/ig, "_");


    var data = {
      id : a_id ,
      reference : name,
      service_type : service_type,
      actual: price,
      amount : price,
      flag : 0,
      rfqId : rfq_id,
      clientid : client_id,
      serviceId : service_id
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: absolute1 + 'cart/add_cart',
        data: data,
        success: function (response) {
          addedCart=1;
          $.toast({
            heading: 'Success',
            text: 'Service successfully added in cart',
            showHideTransition: 'slide',
            icon: 'success',
            loaderBg: '#f96868',
            position: 'top-right'
          });
          // $("#paymentCart_"+a_id).attr("disabled", true);
          $("#paymentCart_"+a_id).html('Added');
           $(".cartcount").text(response);
        }
    });
  }
```

**Button**

```
<button title="Pay Now" type="button" data-id="<?=$addToCart?>" id="paymentCart_<?=$addToCart;?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-icon btnAddAction refresh-me add-to-cart cart-action has-spinner" style="padding: 0;width:95px; height:30px;" onclick="javascript:advAddtocart(<?=$addToCart;?>)">Add to Cart</button>
```

Comment: Update your post with some HTML too.

Answer (score 0):

**absolute1** variable is not defined , define it **before ajax call**

and try to add error handler for ajax

```
.error(function(e){
   console.log(e);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to change the text of the button using class '.cartcount' but there's no such '.cartcount' class in the buttons class. Why not use the button's id?

```
$('#btn-id').text('TEXT HERE');
```